# DEBUG = True still 500 error

Tags: python, django, wsgi, internal-server-error

I went into settings.py in the Django Framework for my site because I had run into a 500 Internal Server Error. I'd heard that this happens when DEBUG = False, however, my DEBUG is set to True and it still does not give me anything more specific than a 500 Internal Server Error.

My site was running perfectly fine and all of a sudden this error occurred...any thoughts?? I checked my wsgi link and nothing had changed there as well!

Comment: What about apache error logs? There should be a traceback.

Comment: What's the value of `TEMPLATE_DEBUG`? You might want to try setting that to `True` as well.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug) for more information.

Comment: Django error log could be useful too, it can be a problem with settings.py in which case you might not get the standard verbose 500 error page

Comment: I know the OP checked this, but for anyone else landing here, in my case it was some changes to the wsgi.py file (in the same location as the settings.py) which caused this problem.